# Question about variational inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a question about the following proposition.

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $x^* \in H^*$ a bounded functional, $U\subseteq H$ a closed linear subspace and $\bar{u} \in U$. Then $\Re x^*(u-\bar{u})\leq\Re (\bar{u},u-\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$ if and only if $x^*(u)=(u,\bar{u})$ for every $u\in U$.

$\Re, \Im$ are real and imaginary parts, and it is assumed that the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is linear in the first slot.

*Context*. This equivalence helps in proving properties of the metric projection onto closed subspaces, and also the Riesz representation theorem.

*Try*. The proof proceeds as follows:

1. show that $\Re x^*(u-\bar{u})\leq\Re (\bar{u},u-\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$ is equivalent to $\Re x^*(u-\bar{u})\leq\Re (u-\bar{u},\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$
2. use linearity of $U$ and $x^*$ to prove $\Re x^*(u-\bar{u})\leq\Re (u-\bar{u},\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$ holds if and only if the equality holds
3. still using linearity of $U$ and $x^*$ we can easily prove that $\Re x^*(u-\bar{u})=\Re (u-\bar{u},\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$ holds if and only if $\Im x^*(u-\bar{u})=\Im (u-\bar{u},\bar{u})$ for every $u \in U$
4. put together all the pieces and conclude

What I don't have clear is how to prove step $1$.It seems to me that we are shifting the linearity of the inner product to the wrong slot if we proved it, and I don't see a way of doing so, since we have the real parts in between. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $(x,y) = (y,x)$ so $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is antilinear in the second slot. We have $(\overline{u},\overline{u}) \in \Bbb{R}$ so
$$(\overline{u},u-\overline{u}) = (\overline{u},u) - (\overline{u},\overline{u}) = \overline{( u,\overline{u})} -(\overline{u},\overline{u}) = \overline{(u,\overline{u})- (\overline{u},\overline{u})}  = \overline{(u-\overline{u},\overline{u})}$$
so $(\overline{u},u-\overline{u})$ and $(u-\overline{u},\overline{u})$ have equal real parts.

Comment: Thank you: I was wondering however why the second last equality holds

Comment: @warm_fish Sorry, it is a mistake, I removed it now.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer